# pandas csv imports floats as str after row 65535 with no difference in source csv, set low_memory=False warning on import

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, csv

I have a 106k row csv. Lines 65530 through 65540 are

```
65530.0,XX/USD,1643482694890045000,sell,8.793,0.3,True,65530.0,1.0,1.0,8.793,0.3,0.0,0.0
65531.0,XX/USD,1643482695820627000,sell,8.793,0.3,True,65531.0,1.0,1.0,8.793,0.3,0.0,0.0
65532.0,XX/USD,1643482696697503000,sell,8.793,0.3,True,65532.0,1.0,1.0,8.793,0.3,0.0,0.0
65533.0,XX/USD,1643482697716654000,sell,8.793,0.3,True,65533.0,1.0,1.0,8.793,0.3,0.0,0.0
65534.0,XX/USD,1643482698627121000,sell,8.793,0.3,True,65534.0,1.0,1.0,8.793,0.3,0.0,0.0
65535.0,XX/USD,1643482699821714000,sell,8.793,0.3,True,65535.0,1.0,1.0,8.793,0.3,0.0,0.0
65534.0,XX/USD,1643482698627121000,sell,8.793,0.3,True,65534.0,1.0,1.0,8.793,0.3,0.0,0.0
65535.0,XX/USD,1643482699821714000,sell,8.793,0.3,True,65535.0,1.0,1.0,8.793,0.3,0.0,0.0
65536.0,XX/USD,1643482700776673000,sell,8.793,0.3,True,65536.0,1.0,1.0,8.793,0.3,0.0,0.0
65537.0,XX/USD,1643482701707969000,sell,8.793,0.3,True,65537.0,1.0,1.0,8.793,0.3,0.0,0.0
65538.0,XX/USD,1643482702710212000,sell,8.793,0.3,True,65538.0,1.0,1.0,8.793,0.3,0.0,0.0
```

so no interesting change...

```
sum([type(df.price[x])!=float for x in range(0,df.shape[0])])
Out[146]: 40647
sum([type(df.price[x])==float for x in range(0,df.shape[0])])
Out[147]: 65536
```

for some reason though the last 40647 rows are showing up as `str`s?

```
type(df.price[65536])
Out[149]: str
type(df.price[65535])
Out[150]: float
```

I'm not seeing this as an issue when opening the csv in openoffice or in sublime text editor. What is pandas doing?

I'm just vanilla importing. I do get this warning though?

```
pd.read_csv(full_chosen_path_list[0])
<ipython-input-151-03a220273804>:1: DtypeWarning:
Columns (4,6) have mixed types. Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.
```

My computer has 64gb of ram which is mostly unused, other files are larger, formatted identically, and aren't having this issue (over 100 similar files worked)

Also, there's nothing really interesting about columns 4 and 6, why would those columns be having the issue but not the other columns?
column 6 is a bool column that turns to str at row 65537 too

Comment: My understanding is that when pandas reads a large file it does so in chunks. This means that if in one chunk col 4 looks like [1,1,2,2,...] but another it's [1,1,1,'A',...] in one chunk pandas says "oh it's a number" the other it says "nope that col is an object' then when it gives you the df it upcasts to object because numeric types can't hold 'A'. If you set low_memory=False then it will parse the entire file at once, avoiding the above. Or if you explicitly specify the dtype it will use that (or complain it can't use the type you specified)

Comment: Basically, somewhere in those columns you have some bad data, likely after row 65535. It could be something as benign as `'-'` or `'.'` to indicate null values, or a typo in one of the numbers. Basically if pandas can't read a **single** value into the correct dtype it will upcast that entire column on import. This is why most data cleaning is done after import with functions like `pd.to_numeric` that have more power to `coerce` bad values that typically ruin conversions on import

Comment: ah, so there could be a string somewhere between 65537 and eof, then it auto-sets that entire chunk to str, even the non-strs? (edit: looks like we were typing this explanation out at the same time. Got it.)

Comment: Yes, the `dtype` of a pandas Series needs to be capable of storing **every** single value in that column. So if you have a column of 10 Trillion numbers, but a single row has the letter 'A'  the dtype of that Series needs to be Object. Ofc you can clean that column so that the 'A' is replaced with NaN which can then become numeric, but it's really an all or nothing for dtypes.

Comment: For the boolean column check `df['that_col'].unique()`, which should make it easy to spot the offending value.